# Axios post fails with 403 error code and showing CSRF token validation failed but works fine django api when passing csrftoken in header with Postman

Tags: reactjs, django, axios, react-router

I am tring to send csrf token by using axios post in react js but csrf token validation is failing. I am also done `with credentials:true` 
but it's not working.I am receving csrf token in cookie but not able to send it.

```
class LoginService extends Component {


loginUser(formData)
{
    const config = {     
        headers: { 'content-type': 'application/json',
        'X-CSRFToken': Cookies.get("csrftoken")}
    }
   return  axios.post(`${API_BASE_URL}api/user/v1/account/login_session/`,formData,config);
}
```

}

Comment: add your axios code to your post.

Comment: @MalcolmInTheCenter  I have added the code please check it out

Comment: Are you sure of the header key, I see 'X-CSRF-TOKEN' in other sources. Are you using 'devlopment tools' to see the cookie name and what is sended by the request ? Also withCredentials is an Axios option, not an header, the braket is not on the right place

Comment: @ JB_DELR yes i m using development tools and i am getting csrf token like:-

Cookie:csrftoken=arpsAQYsqEQltpgzys8ELIPMLYGF2vUkmUuEUaydA7ZyiVFHBZjzjo4uiofLxIGt

Answer (score 1):

If you are using httpsOnly cookies then `'X-CSRFToken': Cookies.get("csrftoken")}` will not work.

> **What is HttpOnly?**
>
> According to the Microsoft Developer Network,
> HttpOnly is an additional flag included in a Set-Cookie HTTP response
> header. Using the HttpOnly flag when generating a cookie helps
> mitigate the risk of client side script accessing the protected cookie
> (if the browser supports it).

Using `withCredentials: true` should suffice.

```
loginUser(formData)
{
    const config = {     
        headers: { 'content-type': 'application/json' },
        withCredentials: true
    }
   return axios.post(`${API_BASE_URL}api/user/v1/account/login_session/`,formData,config);
  }
}
```

> withCredentials indicates whether or not cross-site Access-Control
> requests   should be made using credentials
> withCredentials: false,
> // default

Of course you also need to ensure the cookie **domain** is set correctly in order for the cookie to work.

**Tip:** Check your chrome network inspector, and see whether the desire cookie is sent together with your request

#### CSRF with HttpOnly

If you are setting csrf cookie with httpOnly you can remove httpOnly.

There's an answer with regards to this here https://security.stackexchange.com/a/175540/135413

Comment: I tried with the above react code and my cookie setting is as:
def standard_cookie_settings(request):
    """ Returns the common cookie settings (e.g. expiration time). """

    cookie_settings = {
        'domain': settings.SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN,
        'path': '/',
        'httponly': None,
    }

Answer (score 0):

When you send the header in Axios to the server, you need to know if your server-side accepts the patterns: `CSRF-TOKEN` or `X-CSRF-TOKEN` or `XSRF-TOKEN` or `X-XSRF-TOKEN`.

You are using `X-CSRFToken`, that not combine with any patterns shown above.

More here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/csurf

Comment: when I am hitting my api using postman and passing header then it works fine only with X-CSRFToken

Answer (score 0):

**This is how I solve my problem :
first set these two as:-
axios.defaults.xsrfCookieName = "csrftoken";
axios.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = "X-CSRFTOKEN";
**

```
loginUser(formData)
{
    const config = {     
        headers: { 'content-type': 'application/json'},
        "X-CSRFToken": Cookies.get('csrftoken'),
        withCredentials: true
    }
   return  axios.post(`${API_BASE_URL}api/user/v1/account/login_session/`,formData,config);
}
```

}